# Ruby on Rails - Can't access the updated model from Slim View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, slim-lang

I have a view for editing my model. I am using Slim views.

My model_name is 'cupcake'

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, :order, record] do |f|
  .row
    .col-md-6
      label for="_kind" Kind
      = f.select :kind, [['Clipart', :clipart], ['Image', :image], ['Message', :message]], { selected: record[:kind] }, value: record[:kind], class: 'form-control', :input_html => { :name => "cupcake[:kind]" }
    - if @record[:kind] == 'image'
      .col-xs-12
        = f.input :image, as: :shrine_file
    - elsif @record[:kind] == 'clipart'
      .col-md-6
        label for="_clipart" Clipart
        = f.select :clipart_id, options_for_select(@cliparts.map { |c| [c['name'], c['id'], {'value' => c['id']}] }, selected_key = selected_clipart(record).id), { selected: selected_clipart(record).name }, class: 'form-control', :input_html => { :name => "cupcake[:clipart_id]" }
    - else
      .col-md-6
        = f.input :text_line_style, collection: ["Three Line Text","Single Line Text"], checked: record['first_line'] ? 'Three Line Text' : "Single Line Text", as: :radio_buttons, item_wrapper_class: "inline"

  .row
    .col-xs-12
      hr

      button.btn.btn-success.btn-lg
        = fa_icon('check')
        | Save

      - redirect_location = [:admin, :cliparts]

      = link_to redirect_location, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'
        = fa_icon('chevron-left')
        | Back

    .col-xs-12
      - if f.object.created_at.present?
        p.help-block Created at: #{f.object.created_at}

      - if f.object.updated_at.present?
        p.help-block Updated at: #{f.object.updated_at}
```

I want to update the view based on the kind selected. Currently, it is not updating the view if I select a different kind. When I try to access cupcake[:kind], it is showing undefined error. Any way to access the cupcake object? I looked for it in the f object. But, I couldn't find it.

Anyone, please help?

Comment: Do you mean `if I select a different kind and save the form`? Is a `kind` another model or just a field of Cupcake? `I try to access cupcake[:kind]` - where you tried to access it?

Comment: kind is a field of Cupcake. The values can be 'image', 'clipart' or 'message'

Comment: I need to modify the if condition. I would like to access like: - if cupcake[:kind] == 'image'